# How to create multiple files in one gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have an array which represents generated files and their contents,

```
[{name: "src/js/file1.js",content: "some js content"},
 {name: "src/file2.html",content: "some html content"},
 {name: "src/css/file3.css",content: "some css content"}]
```

The files do not yet exist on the file system, how do I plug them into a gulp pipe line so they get created before any other gulp tasks are set loose on them? I have looked at the gulp-foreach and gulp-file but I have no clue how to stick them together and get that to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution I went with... it's kind of hackish but hey it works! Please suggest any and all improvements. If you like it vote me up thanks!

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
var file = require("gulp-file");
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');
var files = [{name: "src/js/file1.js",content: "some js content"},
             {name: "src/file2.html",content: "some html content"},
             {name: "src/css/file3.css",content: "some css content"}];

gulp.task("default", function() {   
    return gulp.src("./dummy.txt", {base: "./.build"})
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, f){
        files.forEach(function(gfile){
            stream
                .pipe(file(gfile.name, gfile.content))
                .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
        });
        return stream;
    }))
    .pipe(addsrc(["./.build/**/*", "!./dummy.txt"]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./app"));
}
```